# Blocking numbers from my phone and WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, sms-blocking

If I block a contact on my phone can they still message me on WhatsApp? Will I have to block them on WhatsApp separately?

Answer (score 1):

Blocking a contact will **not** prevent that user from sending you messages on WhatsApp.

Hence, you need to explicitly block that contact using the WhatsApp settings.

Here is what happens when you block someone in WhatsApp:

- WhatsApp messages sent by a blocked contact will not show up on your phone and will never be delivered to you.
- You will not be able to send messages to a blocked contact until you unblock them.

There is one important feature blocking does not change:

- Blocking someone will not remove this contact from your WhatsApp list, nor will it remove you from the list on this contact's phone. To delete a contact in WhatsApp, you must delete the contact from your phone's address book.